# Can't append Excel sheet with xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

i'm creating a table in Excel sheet, the issue is that my code erase the other existing sheets
and appends option doesnt work with *xlsxwriter*

```
    with pd.ExcelWriter('Template.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='SheetName', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['SheetName']
        (max_row, max_col) = df.shape
        column_settings = [{'header': column} for column in df.columns]
        worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1
                            , {'columns': column_settings
                               ,"name": "TableName"}
                            )
        worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 12)
    writer.save()
```

Any solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found that *xlsxwriter* can't append it cas only write (erase other sheets if exists).
The solution is to use *openpyxl* and this is an exemple of code :

```
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl import Workbook        # Module needed for creating new workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook   # Module needed for loading existing workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb["sheetName"]

for row in dataframe_to_rows(dataframe, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(row)
wb.save(filename)
```